# How do I expose a contextual filter?

Tags: views, 8

I have created a view that shows few entities. To be able to see only a particular entity, I created a contextual filter.

How can I expose the contextual filter I added?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! There isn't anything you need to do: The Views module applies both the contextual filter and the other filters to filter the entities to show.

Comment: I see, but how can I make contextual filter exposed for the user?

Comment: That is not the question you are asking, since _sum up_ doesn't mean _exposing the contextual filter to the users_.

Comment: Sorry, I will create a new question

Comment: There is no need to create a new question. It's enough to make this question clearer, which is what I did.

Comment: Just add it as a normal Filter Criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contextual filter is an an argument to the view, for example through the path or block/plugin context.

It is not visible to the user, it's visible to Drupal.

If you want something to be visible to the user, you need to instead add a filter and then tick the checkbox to expose it, creating a so called "exposed filter". That should then show up in a filter form.